# Importing VMs from another VMware Server 2.0 host

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

I have two VMware servers (version 2.0). The primary one is already up and running and in production. It's hosting a printer server and a DHCP server. We have two machines set up. Server 1 is 2008 SP2 32-bit host running two 2008 64-bit guests. Server 2 is a 2008 R2 SP0 64-bit host. I have the datastore folder and share mirrored from Server1 to Server2.

I can add the machine to Inventory, but when I try to run it, I get a message:

```
msg.uuid.altered:This virtual machine may have been moved or copied.
In order to configure certain management and networking features VMware Server needs to know which.
Did you move this virtual machine, or did you copy it?
If you don't know, answer "I copied it".
```

The bootup of the machine fails with the message:

```
"Power On Virtual Machine" failed to complete. If these problems persist, please contact your system administrator.DetailsCannot open the disk 'c:\Datastore\DoaAncPs01\DoaAncPs01-000001.vmdk' or one of the snapshot disks it depends on.
Reason: Failed to lock the file.
```

How do I backup and restore these Vm images?

Comment: The first message is typical. Basically, it just wants to know whether it's going to run into trouble (copied with the other machine running) or if you moved it. That's a normal response, and you should answer appropriately.  As for the second error, take a look here: http://communities.vmware.com/message/875351

Comment: Awesome all I had to do was delete the .lck files. Thank you very much.

Comment: Actually, the question has a more serious reason: The machine's UUID (and all other "unique" stuff like MAC addresses) are generated *once*. If both machines are powered on in the same network segment, you *will* run into problems unless selecting the "I copied it" response, which regenerates all IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the .lck file from the Virtual Machine's folder (e.g. C:\Virtual Machines). 
These files are the lock files that should only exist while your VM is powered on. Delete the .lck files and power the VM up.

For more info, check out the [article in my blog.](http://binyit.blogspot.com/2013/07/making-vmware-server-2-work-on-windows-8.html)

Comment: Page which is referred to in the asnwer is gone..

Comment: Link is modified.